# Getting the search to work in an encrypted field

Tags: moqui

Recently, I posted a question related to a search issue ([Search not working (as expected) for list-form PartyListForm - column loaded from mantle.party.PartyIdentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776720/search-not-working-as-expected-for-list-form-partylistform-column-loaded-fro)).

In testing, I found out that the search behaves awkwardly and returns unexpected results. After a minute of analysis, I found out the root. I implemented the search in an encrypted field.

Is there a way the search can work, so that it searches through the real values, not the encrypted ones?

[ID values in PartyIdentificationDetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1A4A.png)

[ID values shown on a screen in a readable format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atoxm.png)

Comment: What is the PartyIdentificationDetail entity? That is not a standard one in Mantle. In the UI the fields should always show decrypted.

Comment: Are doing searches using the like or equals? The equals operator should work, the entity facade encrypts find values before sending to the database to do a match (the encryption algorithm produces consistent values). The only way to use the like operator is to not encrypt the entity field.

Comment: I use the like operator. I shall consult it with the users and if they insist on it, I shall switch the encryption to off.